# Pandas isin vs Numpy in1d

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm subsetting a dataframe based on values from a list, and planned to use df.isin, but got only an Empty Dataframe. I found the handy np.in1d function from another post, which works great. I'm just not sure why df.isin didn't work. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Bob', 8], ['Sally', 7], ['Sally', 10]], columns = ['name', 'score'])
print(df)

    name  score
0    Bob      8
1  Sally      7
2  Sally     10
```

Next, np.in1d works as advertised.

```
namelist = [['Sally', 'Betty', 'Harry']]
sally_np = df[np.in1d(df['name'], namelist)]
print(sally_np)

    name  score
1  Sally      7
2  Sally     10
```

Finally, df.isin returns an empty dataframe, since the boolean values came up false. Anybody know why this comparison is coming up false?

```
sally = df[df['name'].isin(namelist)]
print(sally)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, score]
Index: []

print(df['name'].isin(values=namelist))

0    False
1    False
2    False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the names out of the nested loop:

```
namelist = ['Sally', 'Betty', 'Harry']
```

It's failing because it's searching a list of length 1, where the only element is a list